# Testing with multiple settings in NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I got an application with two types of users. Say, we got user

- A (password: 1234)
- B (password: ABCD)

This is an example for a test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestCalls
{
    private static RestApiClient client;

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        client = new RestApiClient("http://localhost:1234/");
        SetToken("A", "1234");
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ExampleTest()
    {
        // a test methods
        var value = await client.ExecuteRequestAsync(...);

        Assert.That(value, Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty)
        // more assertions
    }
}
```

`SetToken` simply sets the authentication-token on my `RestApiClient`-insance.

The problem is that user A gets other values than user B (same type of course, different values, but another database)

I could solve it with using `TestCaseAttribute` but I want to have the `SetToken` in `SetUpAttribute`-method `Init()`

```
[Test]
[TestCase("A")]
[TestCase("B")]
public async Task ExampleTest(string user)
{
    SetToken(user, "1234"); // of course setting right password

    // a test methods
    var value = await client.ExecuteRequestAsync(...);

    Assert.That(value, Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty)
    // more assertions
}
```

Is there any possibility to have s.th like configurations for NUnit? So I could run everything twice (for both users)?
Or what could I do to test both users? 
(Copy-pasting all tests is not a solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

We can add multiple `TestFixture`-attributes and give them values.
We need to define a constructor for the test-class with the same amount of arguments.
Then in the constructor we assign those values to fields (here I'm using private readonly fields)

And then we can use them in the `SetUp`.

NUnit automatically creates now test-cases for both users.

my Test-class looks like this now:

```
[TestFixture("A", "1234")]
[TestFixture("B", "ABCD")]
public class TestCalls
{
    private static RestApiClient client;

    private readonly string username;
    private readonly string password;

    public TestCalls(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        client = new RestApiClient("http://localhost:1234/");
        SetToken(this.username, this.password);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task ExampleTest()
    {
        // a test methods
        var value = await client.ExecuteRequestAsync(...);

        Assert.That(value, Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty)
        // more assertions
    }
}
```